# How to solve a system of two equations with two unknowns?

Tags: systems-of-equations, problem-solving, economics

So i'm working through a Cournot duopoly problem. Here is the answer sheet with the question and the explanation of the various steps.
[image]

[image]

Im perfectly fine finding q1 and q2 but im having problems getting to the answer 8.11)

How do i find that solution? What method do i need to use ? Could somebody please explain? How is this method called?

I tried subsituting q2 into q1 but it gets really messy.

Thanks!

EDIT:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could rewrite (8.9) and (8.10) as

$$2bq_1= A -bq_2-c$$
$$2bq_2= A -bq_1-c$$

Subtract the two equations from each other,

$$ 2b(q_1-q_2)= b(q_1-q_2)$$

or $b(q_1-q_2)=0$, which yields $q_1=q_2$. Plugging this back to the two equations above, you get $3q_1=3q_2=A-c$, or

$$q_1=q_2=\frac{A-c}{3b}$$

Edit: Plug (8.9) into (8.10)

$$q_2=\frac{ A -b\frac{ A -bq_2-c}{2b}-c}{2b}$$
$$=\frac{ A -\frac12( A -bq_2-c)-c}{2b}$$
$$=\frac{ \frac12 A +\frac12 bq_2-\frac12c}{2b}=\frac{  A + bq_2-c}{4b}=\frac14q_2+\frac{  A-c}{4b}$$

Then, move $\frac14q_2$ to the LHS to get
$$q_2-\frac14q_2=\frac{  A-c}{4b}\implies \frac34q_2=\frac{  A-c}{4b}\implies q_2 =\frac{  A-c}{3b} $$

Comment: is there any way i can do this with derivatives=?

Comment: @GiuliaDellaRosa - Derivatives are usually used for finding critical points. or extrema, which is not useful for solving system of linear equations.

Comment: is there any simpler way i could do this?

Comment: ive tried plugging q1 into q2 but it always gives me the wrong answer.

Comment: @GiuliaDellaRosa - you mean plug (8.9) into (8.10) to solve for q2

Comment: yes, i did it both on symbolab and on my ti nspire cx cas and they give me different results.

Comment: @GiuliaDellaRosa - see the edit in the answer

Comment: I greatly appreciate your help, really. i have one last question: on my calculator i get that q2=(a-c+by)/4b. Is this correct? Meaning, is there any way i can isolate the y and get the correct answer? I plugged all the right equations, and it continues to give me this answer.

Comment: @GiuliaDellaRosa - Comparing with my derivation in the edit, I believe y is q2. If so, the same steps apply.